# Hazelcast cluster and Replication map synchronization

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast cluster with 2 instances (running from Docker containers) and a Replicated map which is filled at initialization at the first instance. All works fine and quick. Recently I experienced several times the following situation:

1. first instance restarted all of sudden, joined the Hazelcast cluster and started to sync data but didn't finish
2. second instance restarted immediately after as well for no reason; it joined the Hazelcast cluster and synced all data from first instance

I ended up with a healthy cluster but in reality the cluster contained only partial data which were synced before instance 2 shut down. It took at least one day to observe this bad state and to refresh the data.

This problem happened in multiple environments (test, prod). The reasons why the instances restarted are unknown. My Hazelcast version: 3.7.2.
My assumption is the same can happen with 3 or more instances too with less probability.

What are the best practices in a case like this? Thanks!

Comment: What means the instance restarted for no reason? When a JVM crashes it is normally not automatically restarted, Hazelcast itself doesn't restart anything. Not sure I get what you mean by restart? Do you run in a virtualized environment that might restart containers / VMs?

Comment: I forgot to add (I edited my post, thanks). Restart = restart of docker container.

Comment: Check the logs of the docker containers why they got restarted. I am suspecting they might be going OOM or something due to which the container might have got shutdown and container service started it again. Are you running the dockers on AWS ?

Answer (score 2):

if the second instance is restarted before the new instance got the state, you can not expect to recover the whole data.

Comment: Thanks, Ihsan. I had the same intuition. Actually, I can retrieve data easily back into the cluster. But I need some sort of mechanism for alerting: listeners, flags to tell me that replication didn't finish, something around this. A replication map is very poor in this so I hope for a workaround.

Comment: You can use PartitionLostListener to figure out which partition got lost.

Comment: I already add a PLL to my implementation. It is not enough guarantee as the partitioning and replication are separated processes.

Answer (score 0):

Cache is only caching data.Try to design your soft with a guess that cache may invalid or lose data all the time.There is also a machanism in hazelcast to load data from db when the data is not hitted.But this is not recommended,because it couples the cache and db.My proposal is that when data is lost, loading from db in your application.

Comment: I have a mechanism to retrieve data if they are lost. My big problem is to recognize in the system that the restart was unsuccessful. I have metrics reporting the cache size so eventually I could recognize. I am still wandering if I could have some flags at the replication map level.